# How to start a activity in another activity? Zxing

Tags: android

Is it possible to recover the result of the creation of a QR Code ZXing in my own Activity (my xml file)?

Comment: can you give more detail for your question?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you are asking for, but you you can scan a barcode using ZXING from one of your activities like this:

```
                try {
                    Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
                    intent.putExtra("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN.SCAN_MODE", "QR_CODE_MODE");
                    intent.putExtra("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN.SCAN_MODE", "PRODUCT_MODE");
                    startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
                }
                catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {


                }
```

To do something with the barcode include this:

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
        if (requestCode == 0) {

            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

                String contents = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT");

                String format = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT_FORMAT");


                Toast.makeText(this, contents, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
                // Handle cancel
            }
        }
    }
```

You need to have the [ZXING barcode app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.zxing.client.android&hl=en) installed on your device.

Comment: thank you for your response.
this is what I have already done, I want to move the image result (the QR code result) in my view, this is exactly my question